# При переходе на активность, она не отображается, отображается белый лист

Tags: android, activity, android-manifest

При переходе на активность, открывается пустая активность, помогите исправить.
Код MainActivity:

```
package com.example.chasie.myapp6;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String ACTION_SECOND_ACTIVITY = "com.example.chasie.myapp6.SecondActivity";
public static final String ACTION_FIRST_ACTIVITY = "com.example.chasie.myapp6.FirstActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button frst_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.frst_btn);
    Button scnd_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scnd_btn);
    //Button back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

    frst_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_FIRST_ACTIVITY));
        }
    });

    scnd_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

/*public void firstClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}*/
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chasie.myapp6">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/first"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.chasie.myapp6.FirstActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/second"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.chasie.myapp6.SecondActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Вот что получается при переходе по любой активности:
[image: реальность]

А должно:

[image: ожидание]

Код acttivity_first.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/first"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:id="@+id/back_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код SecondActivity.java:

```
package com.example.chasie.myapp6;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by chasie on 24.09.16.
 */

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle     persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        Button back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Было бы лучше еще `.xml` файл активити добавили бы

Comment: @KryTer_NexT Добавил

Comment: такой вызов неправильный. `startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_FIRST_ACTIVITY));`. Он не сработает, как надо. Покажите код SecondActivity.java

Comment: @metalurgus Код добавил, я пробовал различные способы, ни один не работает, как можно заметить SecondActivity вызывается по другому, но эффект одинаковы

Comment: @metalurgus А почему не сработает, у него же в манифесте intent-filter стоит на эту активити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трудно сказать почему у вас не запускается первое `acivity`, потому что вы только разметку показали, но второе `activity` судя по всему отображает вам белый экран из-за метода `onCreate`

в `SecondActivity.java` попробуйте заменить это:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle     persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        Button back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

на это:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        Button back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение помогло. Немного погуглив я понял почему у меня не отображалась `Activity`. Она не отображалась, т.к. в `PersistableBundle     persistentState` по умолчанию передавался `null` и поэтому ничего не отображалось